# second and third letter error in implementation of vigenere cipher in mips

Tags: assembly, encryption, mips, mips32, vigenere

I am trying to do vigenere cipher in mips. I am running into constant error at second and third characters. Later however the inputs are numbers, space, small and capital letters they are getting printed correctly. 
I have incremented the counting number as 4 while getting input, so that integers can also be given. Since key is only letters it is incremented by 1

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "\nenter 0 for encryption and 1 for decryption\n"
msg1: .asciiz "enter the plain text\n"
msg2: .asciiz "enter the key\n"
msg3: .asciiz "enter the cipher text\n"
input: .word 100
key: .space 100

.text
# print msg
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg
syscall

#accept user input
li $v0, 5
syscall 
move $a0, $v0

bne $a0, $zero, decryption

#get text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg1
syscall

for1:
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    beq $v0, 10, next
    sb $v0, input($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j for1

next:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall
j for2
#la $t0,($a0)       #t0 plaintext
#li $t1,0       #t1 length of string

for2:
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    beq $v0, 10, encrypt
    sb $v0, key($t2)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j for2

encrypt:
    bge $t1, $t0, end
    lb $t4, input($t1)
    bge $t3, $t2, z
    lb $t5, key($t3)
    j encrypt2

z:
la $t3,0
j encrypt

encrypt2:
    blt $t4, 65, spl1
    ble $t4, 90, encryptupper
    j encryptlower  

encryptupper:
    li $t7,26
    subi $t4, $t4, 65   #ptext is sub
    bge $t5, 97, smallkeyeupper #check key is small
    subi $t5, $t5, 65   # caps key is sub
    continue2:
    add $t4, $t4, $t5   #key is added to ptext
    div $t4, $t7
    mfhi $a0
    addi $a0, $a0, 65
    j printCipher

smallkeyeupper:
    subi $t5, $t5, 97
    j continue2

encryptlower:
    li $t7,26
    subi $t4, $t4, 97   #ptext is sub
    bge $t5, 97, smallkeyelower #check key is small
    subi $t5, $t5, 65   # caps key is sub
    continue1:
    add $t4, $t4, $t5   #key is added to ptext
    div $t4, $t7
    mfhi $a0
    addi $a0, $a0, 97
    j printCipher

smallkeyelower:
    subi $t5, $t5, 97
    j continue1

spl1:
    bne $t4, 32, printnum1
    li $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j encrypt

printnum1:
    subi $a0, $t4, 48
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        #goes to next ciphertext
    j encrypt

printCipher:
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    #add $t0, $t0, 1        #points to next char of plaintext
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        #increments the length of the plaintext
    addi $t3, $t3, 1        #increments the length of the key
    j encrypt

decryption:

#get text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg3
syscall

for3:
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    beq $v0, 10, next1
    sb $v0, input($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    j for3

next1:li $v0, 4
la $a0, msg2
syscall
j for4
#la $t0,($a0)       #t0 plaintext
#li $t1,0       #t1 length of string

for4:
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    beq $v0, 10, decrypt
    sb $v0, key($t2)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1
    j for4

decrypt:
    bge $t1, $t0, end
    lb $t4, input($t1)
    bge $t3, $t2, y
    lb $t5, key($t3)
    j decrypt2

y:
la $t3,0
j decrypt

decrypt2:
    blt $t4, 65, spl2
    ble $t4, 90, decryptupper
    j decryptlower  


decryptupper:
    li $t7, 26
    subi $t4, $t4, 65   #ciphertext is sub
    bge $t5, 97, smallkeydupper #check key is small
    subi $t5, $t5, 65   #caps key is sub
    cont2:
    add $t4, $t4, $t7   #add 26 
    sub $t4, $t4, $t5   #cipher-key
    div $t4, $t7        #div to get modulo
    mfhi $a0        #modulo
    addi $a0, $a0, 65
    j printPlain

smallkeydupper:
    subi $t5, $t5, 97
    j cont2

decryptlower:
    li $t7,26
    subi $t4, $t4, 97   #ciphertext is sub
    bge $t5, 97, smallkeydlower #check key is small
    subi $t5, $t5, 65   #caps key is sub
    cont1:
    add $t4, $t4, $t7   #add 26
    sub $t4, $t4, $t5   #ciphertext-key
    div $t4, $t7        #div to get modulo
    mfhi $a0        #modulo
    addi $a0, $a0, 97
    j printPlain

smallkeydlower:
    subi $t5, $t5, 97
    j cont1

spl2:
    bne $t4, 32, printnum
    li $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j decrypt

printnum:
    subi $a0, $t4, 48
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        #goes to next ciphertext
    j decrypt

printPlain:
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    #add $t0, $t0, 1    #points to next char of plaintext
    addi $t1, $t1, 4        #increments the length of the plaintext
    addi $t3, $t3, 1        #increments the length of the key
    j decrypt

end:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Please help me with this

```
enter 0 for encryption and 1 for decryption
0
enter the plain text
hello
enter the key
world
dkuwr
```

Instead of 'dscwr'

Comment: _"I have incremented the counting number as 4 while getting input, so that integers can also be given"_. I'm not sure what you mean by _"integers can be given"_ (?). Your input is a series of characters, each of which is 1 byte.

Comment: Life will get much easier if you first filter out the special characters, then check if something is upper or lowercase and remember that. Then you convert to uppercase or lowercase always. When you've done that you convert to an index in the alphabet, with 0 for A and do the same thing for the key character (the position in the key is incremented modulo the key size for each encrypted character). Then you can perform modular addition and finally convert back to the right character. You can then fix the casing where required.